# Call Word.SaveAs method from IronPython

Tags: .net, ms-word, ironpython

I used to manipulate Word from C# and now I test it with IronPython.
Here is my code :

```
import clr

clr.AddReference('System')
clr.AddReference('mscorlib')
clr.AddReference('Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word')
from System.Reflection import Missing
from Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word import ApplicationClass

missing = Missing.Value

word = ApplicationClass()
word.Visible = True
doc = word.Documents.Add(missing, missing, missing, missing)

doc_file_name = r"C:\MyWord.docx"
doc.SaveAs(doc_file_name, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing)
doc.Close(missing, missing, missing)
WordApp.Quit(missing, missing, missing)
```

The ligne with the SaveAs call causes an error : ValueError: Could not convert argument 0 for call to SaveAs.

Did anyone encounter the same problem or have a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the value of file type and if your instance of word is in compatibility mode or not.

I made these changes and it saved fine.

```
doc_file_name = r"C:\MyWord.doc"
doc.SaveAs(doc_file_name)
```

This change bombed out.

```
doc_file_name = r"C:\MyWord.docx"
doc.SaveAs(doc_file_name)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. But do you know why I can't use the SaveAs method with all the arguments ?

Comment: Only if you have actual values.  I've found (from vba) that it is better to specify only what you need and let the object deal with the defaults.